# refactorfields algorithm sets both length and precision of numbers to 0

Tags: qgis, refactor

I'm working with the Python console of QGIS 3.16.6, trying to write a script that will quickly allow me to refactor a layer fields. I'm using the console because it's a process that I have to repeat several times on layers with the same fields and I need to refield them always in the same way.
After defining the path for the input and utput layer, that's what I coded:

```
processing.run("native:refactorfields", {'INPUT': input, 'FIELDS_MAPPING': 

[{'expression':"ID_OGGETTO",
'length':17,
'name':"ID_OGGETTO_COMPARTO",  
'precision':0,
'type':10},

{'expression':"Comune",
'length':255, 
'name':"NOME_COMUNE",
'precision':0, 
'type':10},

{'expression':"Sezione",
'length':255, 
'name':"NOME_SEZIONE",
'precision':0, 
'type':10},

{'expression':"No_Fiscale",
'length':5, 
'name':"COMUNE_FISCALE",
'precision':0, 
'type':2},

{'expression':"No_Sezione",
'length':3, 
'name':"SEZIONE",
'precision':0, 
'type':2},

{'expression':"Numero_FON",
'length':255, 
'name':"NUMERO_FONDO",
'precision':0, 
'type':2},

{'expression': '\"SUPMQ_FON\"',
'length': 10,
'name': 'SUPERFICIE_MQ_FONDO',
'field_precision': 5,
'type': 6}], 
'OUTPUT': output})
```

The algorithm runs correctly, but if I analyze the output layer (.gpkg) fields, that's what I get:

[image: fields after refactorization]

As you can see, both length and precisions of the numbers (integers and reals) has been set to 0, while the code clearly explicits other values. Someone can explain me why this happens?

Comment: Your Question is missing a question.

Comment: You're right. As you can see in the code, I've set values for length and precision that are not the ones I got in the results. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GeoPackage only have a length limit for `String` an `Blob` as you can see in the [OGC® Geo Package Encoding Standard](https://www.geopackage.org/spec/#table_column_data_types)'s table of data types. Same thing for precision, `Decimal` numbers doesn't have any limit.

In QGIS when you add an attribute to a GeoPackage, the length is only required for a `Text/String` type attribute. Example below :

[image]

[image]